# Windows Server 2008: Third-party softwares for Managing backup's

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration

- Need third party software solutions
  to configure, automated backup from
  one server to another and also to
  manage and catalog backups to DVD's
  and/or other removable media.
- To configure regular automated backups (with restore capacities) of the
  active directory services database,
  registry, boot files, etc
- Powerful restore program to bring back the server to the last stored state, in case of a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [BackupExec](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=backupexec) in the past and been fairly happy with it.  Although I have used it for backing up and restoring files, I've never had to use IDR (or anything similar) to recover from a disaster, so your mileage may vary from here.

As with anything, TEST this product in your environment, including simulating a disaster recovery....

Pros:

> - Specific agents are very product aware

Cons:

> - It can get pricey
> - It can be tempermental
> - It can be overwhelmingly complex